# Why does my shell not accept shortcuts in my remote AIX session?

Tags: unix, keyboard-shortcuts, shell

I'm logging into an AIX 5.3 Machine with putty via SSH.

When I press TAB it will actually insert a TAB instead of trying to complete a statement, up and down keys don't cycle through history but actually move my cursor and things like ctrl-d and control-e only yield gibberish instead of doing what they are supposed to.

This happens both with csh and ksh. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably map the keys properly with "stty", but my solution was to install bash, to the chagrin of the administrators.

Comment: Seconded...bash is wonderful.  I use it on my z/OS systems instead of sh.

Answer (score 0):

To use completion in ksh, you need to use <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>. To fix the other keyboard control use stty as mentioned by Tim.